# Не работают inline кнопки.Вобще

Tags: python, inline

```
check = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
but1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ВК', url='google.com', callback_data='knopka1')
but2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Telegram', url='google.com', callback_data='knopka2')
check.add(but1, but2)
button =  types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
button.row('Назад')
send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пиши мне.', reply_markup=button)
bot.register_next_step_handler(send, next5)
```

Есть блок команд,после запуска кнопка "назад" работает.А вот инлайн кнопки просто не появляются.Действие проиходит в одной функции.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не передаёте в сообщении контейнер с инлайн кнопками

> check = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

Они не будут появляться пока вы их не отобразите передавая в сообщении

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @Jack В одном отправленном сообщении можно использовать только один вид клавиатур, вы уже передаёте клавиатуру button в "send = bot.send_message", выберете одну из клавиатур.

Comment: Спасибо,не знал)